# How do I verify and assert if an animation is playing after clicking a button in XCUITest?

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xcode-ui-testing

I can't seem to find any information when it comes to animation testing on XCUITest.
The scenario that I am testing is that:

`When a button is pressed
Then animation will be displayed on the icon`

How do I do this?

Comment: What happens after the animation is finished? Can the user click the button again and the animation will play a second time? Or does the animation change the the state of the button?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend setting a meaningful `accessibilityValue` on the button when it it's animating, which will let voice over users that something is happening too -- then you can check the `value` property of the corresponding XCUIElement in your test.

```
// product code
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_: UIButton) {
    self.button.accessibilityIdentifier = "MyButton"
    self.button.accessibilityValue = "is animating"
    // start animating your button
}

// Test code
let button = self.app.buttons["MyButton"]
button.tap()
XCTAssertEqual(button.value as! String, "is animating")
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it